# Hide and Display the div after selecting the radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with `cheque` and `cash` radio button and cheque radio is default checked. I also set, If the cheque is checked than displaying the input field. If cash is checked then hide the input field.

I check in the inspect elements, Event is working when selecting the cash but input fields are not hiding when cash is selected.

My issue got resolved using Nisarg Shah answer. Now I tried to submit the form but I am getting the value of cheque radio button but I am not getting the value of cash. Getting error`Undefined index: mode_of_payment`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $status=$_POST['mode_of_payment'];
    echo $status;
}
```

would you help me out in this?
[image]

```js
$('label.mode_of_payment').click(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').attr('checked',null);
    $('label.mode_of_payment').removeClass("checked");
    $(this).prev().attr('checked',"checked");
    $(this).addClass("checked");
})
 $('#subject_section').change(function() {
    if ($('#display_cheque').attr('checked')) {
        $('#display_cheque_field').hide();
    } else {
        $('#display_cheque_field').show();
    }
});
```

```css
  .radio-border{
   border:1px solid #000;
   width: 150px;
   border-radius: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;

  }
  .radio-width-half{
   width: 75px;
  }
 input[type=radio]
    {
        display: none;
    }
    input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background-color: #00a2ff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
    .checked{
      background-color: #00a2ff;
      border-radius: 30px;
      display: block;
      color: #fff;
     }
     label.mode_of_payment {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    transition: all 300ms ;
}
#display_cheque_field
{
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" name="subject_section">
       <div class="radio-border">
        <div class="radio-width-half">
         <input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" value="1" class="display-none" id="display_cheque" checked>
         <label class="mode_of_payment">Cheque</label>
        </div>

        <div class="radio-width-half">
         <input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" value="0" class="display-none">
         <label class="mode_of_payment">Cash</label>
        </div>
      </div><!--radio border-->
<div id="display_cheque_field">
      <input type="text" name="cheque_number" class="form-control"  id="cheque_number" placeholder="Cheque number">
      <input type="text" name="drawee_bank" class="form-control"  id="drawee_bank" placeholder="Bank">

</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: You don't need Javascript for this, CSS can do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind to the `change` event on the entire form, and you don't need to. Since you have already defined a click event to handle checking-unchecking of the radio buttons, you can hide/show the inputs along with them. Your modified event handler could be like this:

```
$('label.mode_of_payment').click(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);
  $('label.mode_of_payment').removeClass("checked");
  $(this).prev().prop('checked', true);
  $(this).addClass("checked");

  if (!$('#display_cheque').prop('checked')) {
    $('#display_cheque_field').hide();
  } else {
    $('#display_cheque_field').show();
  }
})
```

```js
$('label.mode_of_payment').click(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);
  $('label.mode_of_payment').removeClass("checked");
  $(this).prev().prop('checked', true);
  $(this).addClass("checked");
  
  if (!$('#display_cheque').prop('checked')) {
    $('#display_cheque_field').hide();
  } else {
    $('#display_cheque_field').show();
  }
})
```

```css
.radio-border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.radio-width-half {
  width: 75px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  background-color: #00a2ff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

.checked {
  background-color: #00a2ff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

label.mode_of_payment {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

#display_cheque_field {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" name="subject_section">
  <div class="radio-border">
    <div class="radio-width-half">
      <input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" value="1" class="display-none" id="display_cheque" checked>
      <label class="mode_of_payment">Cheque</label>
    </div>

    <div class="radio-width-half">
      <input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" value="0" class="display-none">
      <label class="mode_of_payment">Cash</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--radio border-->
  <div id="display_cheque_field">
    <input type="text" name="cheque_number" class="form-control" id="cheque_number" placeholder="Cheque number">
    <input type="text" name="drawee_bank" class="form-control" id="drawee_bank" placeholder="Bank">

  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Yes, It's working.Thanks for the help. I got one problem if I clicked on submit button when the cheque is checked then I am getting the value 1 but if I checked the cash and clicked on submit then I am getting the error.Undefined index: mode_of_payment

Comment: if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 
 $status=$_POST['mode_of_payment'];
 echo $status;
}

Comment: Instead of `$('#display_cheque').attr('checked')`, try `$('#display_cheque').is(':checked')`.

Comment: @NarendraVerma Ideally that shouldn't happen. But I'm not sure how PHP handles form post events. You might want to post a separate question for the issue, or search online about that.

Comment: I tried but I am not getting the value of cash radio button

Comment: Yup, I can repro the issue in form submission, but I don't know why that happens. You should post a separate question with minimal code to reproduce it.

Comment: I don't have a much more code.I updated code in the question.

Comment: @NarendraVerma I found the issue. You need to use `$(this).prev().prop('checked', true);` to check the radio button, instead of `.attr("checked", "checked")`.

Comment: @NisargShah, But It's not working properly. I mean If I select cash and again select the cheque than input fields are not displaying.

Comment: @NarendraVerma It should work fine. Can you make sure that the click handler in your code is identical to the one in my answer?

Comment: Yes, This time working perfectly. Thanks for the help. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code. Here I have added click event on div of radio button and handled radio button change functionality there itself

```js
$(document).on('click', '.radio-width-half',function() {

 debugger;
      $("input[name=mode_of_payment]",this).prop("checked",true);
    //console.log("radio name = "+$("input[name=mode_of_payment]",this).attr('id'));

    if($('#display_cheque').is(":checked"))
 {
     $('#display_cheque_field').show();
 }
 else{
    $('#display_cheque_field').hide();
 }
});
```

```css
.radio-border{
   border:1px solid #000;
   width: 150px;
   border-radius: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;

  }
  .radio-width-half{
   width: 75px;
  }
 input[type=radio]
    {
        display: none;
    }
    input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background-color: #00a2ff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
    .checked{
      background-color: #00a2ff;
      border-radius: 30px;
      display: block;
      color: #fff;
     }
     label.mode_of_payment {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    transition: all 300ms ;
}
#display_cheque_field
{
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>
<form action="#" method="post" name="subject_section">
       <div class="radio-border">
        <div class="radio-width-half">
         <input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" value="1" class="display-none" id="display_cheque" checked>
         <label class="mode_of_payment">Cheque</label>
        </div>

        <div class="radio-width-half">
         <input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" value="0" class="display-none" id="display_cash">
         <label class="mode_of_payment">Cash</label>
        </div>
      </div><!--radio border-->
<div id="display_cheque_field">
      <input type="text" name="cheque_number" class="form-control"  id="cheque_number" placeholder="Cheque number">
      <input type="text" name="drawee_bank" class="form-control"  id="drawee_bank" placeholder="Bank">

</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have added this css for custom radio not require to use jQuery for this and also added jQuery for show and hide `display_cheque_field`.

```
.radio-width-half{ 
  position: relative;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```js
$("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
if($('#display_cheque')[0].checked) {
   $("#display_cheque_field").css('display' ,'block');
}
else{
   $("#display_cheque_field").css('display' ,'none');
}
});
```

```css
.radio-border{
  border:1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}
.radio-width-half{
  width: 75px;
  position: relative;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-color: #00a2ff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
.checked{
  background-color: #00a2ff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
label.mode_of_payment {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: all 300ms ;
}
#display_cheque_field
{
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" name="subject_section">
   <div class="radio-border">
      <div class="radio-width-half">
         <input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" value="1" class="display-none" id="display_cheque" checked>
         <label class="mode_of_payment">Cheque</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio-width-half">
         <input type="radio" name="mode_of_payment" value="0" class="display-none">
         <label class="mode_of_payment">Cash</label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--radio border-->
   <div id="display_cheque_field">
      <input type="text" name="cheque_number" class="form-control"  id="cheque_number" placeholder="Cheque number">
      <input type="text" name="drawee_bank" class="form-control"  id="drawee_bank" placeholder="Bank">
   </div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```